# Oracle 19 database, FROM_TZ with a timestamp at 10 o'clock is returning the same date at 9 o'clock, only if year >2020

Tags: oracle, dst

With Oracle 19, here is my query :

```
SELECT
  FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 10:00:00', 'Europe/Paris') jan2020,
  FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 10:00:00', 'Europe/Paris') ju2020,
  FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 10:00:00', 'Europe/Paris') jan2021,
  FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2021-06-01 10:00:00', 'Europe/Paris') ju2021
FROM dual;
```

and here is the result :

```
JAN2020                           |JU2020                            |JAN2021                           |JU2021                            |
----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
2020-01-01 10:00:00.0 Europe/Paris|2020-06-01 10:00:00.0 Europe/Paris|2021-01-01 10:00:00.0 Europe/Paris|2021-06-01 09:00:00.0 Europe/Paris|
```

The last result is at **09:00:00**, i expect it to be at 10.

It may be related to the DST file, i checked with `SELECT * FROM V$TIMEZONE_FILE;` and but it's version 32 (timezlrg_32.dat). Since Oracle 19 is a rather recent version, i tend to think this file should cover dates after 2020 (I may be wrong though)

edit: as requested in the comments here is the result from `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`

```
PARAMETER              |VALUE                     |
-----------------------+--------------------------+
NLS_LANGUAGE           |FRENCH                    |
NLS_TERRITORY          |FRANCE                    |
NLS_CURRENCY           |€                         |
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY       |FRANCE                    |
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS |,                         |
NLS_CALENDAR           |GREGORIAN                 |
NLS_DATE_FORMAT        |DD/MM/RR                  |
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE      |FRENCH                    |
NLS_SORT               |FRENCH                    |
NLS_TIME_FORMAT        |HH24:MI:SSXFF             |
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT   |DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF    |
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT     |HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR         |
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT|DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR|
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY      |€                         |
NLS_COMP               |BINARY                    |
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS   |BYTE                      |
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP    |FALSE                     |
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include: the relevant time and territory related output from `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`; and details of the system time zone. Without being able to replicate your settings its difficult to work out what is wrong and [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=57eec40b4bed87877bfd5a20998a4861) does not show the same results as your query (probably because it uses the UTC time zone and your database does not but there are likely to be other differences).

Comment: Why not include the time zone in the literal? `TIMESTAMP '2021-06-01 10:00:00 Europe/Paris'`?

Comment: I edited the question as requested.

I'm not using the timezone in the string litera, because this query is just an example, in the real use case i get the timestazmp from a column and the timezone from another